# Reverse column output with sort command

Tags: command-line, sort

I have to sort all of the words from a file given as parameter in a shell script.
Here is the one-liner:

```
tr  [:space:] '\n' <$1  | sort -nrk2,2 | uniq -c |sed 's/^ \+//g'
```

Basically, if I have something like this in my file:

```
bla bla bla bla hu hu hu
```

It will output

```
4 bla
3 hu
```

I want them to be something like

```
bla 4
hu 3
```

Comment: Also I believe you should replace sort -nrk2,2 with just sort -nr. In this case k2,2 just doesn't do anything since you trimmed the whitespace beforehand (i.e. there is just one field), but normally that wouldn't necessarily produce a file sorted the way uniq -c requires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could replace your `sed` command with a simple `awk` command that swaps the field order

```
... | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: What about if i have, let's say ,2 words with exactly the same number of occurences in a text , but i want to print only the first in alphabetically order ( let's say my output in this case is  steel 4 and driver 4 ,but  i will print only driver 4)?

Comment: @gigiman you could either add an additional `sort -uk1,1` in the pipeline, or modify the awk to build an array of the first result for each count, and output the array at the end of processing e.g. `awk '!a[$1]{a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print a[i],i}'`

Comment: Wow , thanks so much steeldriver you're really a life saver !

Answer (score 6):

There are many, many ways of doing this. Steeldriver already gave you the classic `awk` approach. Here are some other choices:

1. Use `sed` to capture two groups of non-whitespace (`\S`) characters and then switch them around:

   ```
   ... | sed -E 's/\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\2 \1/'
   ```
2. Use `perl`. Its `-a` switch makes it work like `awk`. It will automatically split each input line on whitespace and save each field as an element of the array `@F`. Therefore, the 1st field will be `$F[0]`, the second `$F[1]` etc.:

   ```
   ... | perl -lane 'print "$F[1] $F[0]"'
   ```
3. Use Perl for the whole thing:

   ```
   perl -lane '$k{$_}++ for @F; }{ print "$_ $k{$_}" for keys(%k)' "$1"
   ```

   Here, `perl` reads the input file line by line and applies the script to each line. `$k{$_}++ for @F` saves each word (each field from `@F`) as a key in the hash `%k` and increments the associated value by one each time the word is seen. Then, after the file has been processed (that's what the `}{` means), it will print the word (`$_`) and the number of times it was seen (`$k{$_}`) for each key stored in the hash.
4. Use `awk` for the whole thing:

   ```
   awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++}}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' "$1"
   ```

   The first `for` loop iretares over each field and adds one to the value associated with that field in the array `a`. Then, at the end of the file, it loops over each element in `a` and prints the element (the word) and the associated value (the number of times the word was seen).
5. Use the shell with your original pipeline:

   ```
   ... | while read a b; do echo "$b $a"; done
   ```

Comment: +1 nice roundup! these kinds of questions always make me want to quote [the barometer question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question)

Comment: @steeldriver heh, indeed.

Comment: @terdon thanks alot , now i have a much more ample vision about formatting in bash :)

Comment: Come on Guru..i want some free points too ;)